# To show closedness of a function of random variables

Tags: convergence-divergence, random-variables, holder-inequality, jensen-inequality

Let the function $g(X) := inf_{a \in \mathbb{R}} \{a + E[ \max(X-a, 0)] \}$, where $X$ is a random variable of finite expectation and variance and $\|\cdot\|_2$ is the $2$-norm  in $\mathcal{L}^2$. It is already established that $g$ is convex in X for any $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

I am hoping to show that if $X_k$ is a sequence of random variables such that
\begin{align}
  \|X_k -X\|_2 \rightarrow 0, 
\end{align}
where $g(X_k) \leq 0$ for each $k$,it holds that:
\begin{align}
 g(X) \leq 0.
\end{align}

I assmue that a proof would involve Hölder's inequality ut utilize the fact that $E[|X_k-X|] \longrightarrow 0$ together with Jensen's inequality, using the fact that  $g$ is convex, but I can't seem to find the correct application.